# variadic template argument deduction for function pointer arguments

Tags: c++11

I'm trying to design a function that will take any number of function pointers that return different types. How can I make h compile?

```
#include <string>

template<typename T, typename U>
void g(T(*f1)(void) -> T, U(*f2)(void) -> U) {
}

template<typename ...T>
void h(T(*f)(void) -> T...) {
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  g(
    +[]() -> int { return 123; },
    +[]() -> std::string { return "321"; }
  );

  h(
    +[]() -> int { return 123; },
    +[]() -> std::string { return "321"; }
  );
}
```

It is entirely possible I'm being really stupid here. Is it the parameter expansion Im doing wrong, or something else?

Comment: Ive removed them from the call to h and the function definition, but it still fails to compile

Comment: I meant only the declarations. Also, the `...` turned out to be in a wrong place, see the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need trailing return types in `g` and `f` declarations, and `...` is in a wrong place.

Fixed version:

```
#include <string>

template<typename T, typename U>
void g(T(*f1)(void), U(*f2)(void)) {
}

template<typename ...T>
void h(T(*...f)(void)) {
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  g(
    +[]() -> int { return 123; },
    +[]() -> std::string { return "321"; }
  );

  h(
    +[]() -> int { return 123; },
    +[]() -> std::string { return "321"; }
  );
}
```

Comment: great! for my compiler the trailing return types are irrelevant. Its the position of the ellipsis I couldnt figure out. I had tried `T(*f...)(void)` but not `T(*...f)(void)`